# Ubuntu Kernel Patchset

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu used to provide the list of patch applied on their kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/Specs/SaucyKernelDeltaReview). However that list haven't been updated since Ubuntu 13.10. Is there an updated list somewhere (especially for Ubuntu 20.04)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all patches in Ubuntu kernel git repos, e.g.

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal)